# How can Stack Overflow users be encouraged to use jQuery only when appropriate?

Tags: discussion, answers, quality-improvement

This question is a serious question for anyone who believes there is still just as much importance in understanding the core JavaScript language, even in the post-jQuery world.

In the last seven years, I have followed the development of jQuery and truly appreciate what it does for developers. I have always appreciated writing modular and reusable code like jQuery, as someone who has continuously developed JavaScript applications for 14 years. Everyone who used JavaScript in the pre-jQuery days knew how useful it would be to have a standard JavaScript library that did common things well, and the amazing popularity of jQuery showed just how real that need was.

But it is nothing short of scary to see the unexpected negative side, particularly, the detrimental effect on the overall skill level of programmers.

Some JavaScript programmers with six years of tenure or less are spending more and more of their time learning jQuery, gaining less and less knowledge and understanding of the JavaScript it is based on.

Not long ago, a polished final product was one that contained a small script doing exactly what was needed, although in development it might rely on 10-100 KB of jQuery code with the associated network overhead. But just the opposite is true today. jQuery seems to be an artificial requirement for almost any project large or small, and I shudder every time I see a JavaScript program rely on jQuery when there is no reason.

A perfect example of how bad the problem is: [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript?rq=1)

Already in just six years, I sense a preference for any solution that uses jQuery, even if it actually takes more lines of code to implement in jQuery than in native JavaScript! Worse, there even seem to be a few who automatically consider any code not using jQuery to be suspect.

I am concerned that the same thing will happen with JavaScript that has happened with knowledge of CPU instruction sets, machine language, etc. It is not too much of an exaggeration that if a select group of 1,000 people disappeared, no one else in the world would know how to continue the development of computer chips, and society would change drastically. Web development could certainly reach the same point within 15 years if the knowledge of core languages is not preserved at the level of popular "consumer"-level use.

Is there a way to define a dividing line between appropriate and inappropriate uses of jQuery? And how can we who answer Stack Overflow questions begin to observe that dividing line for the sake of the long-term preservation of JavaScript knowledge in the next 15 years of this important programming language?

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to have us all ditch Gnome/KDE/Qt as well and revert to direct X11? Or give up the Java collections classes and use C arrays? Or throw away our high-level languages altogether and return to assembler? :-) That may seem a fatuous comment but it's not. The whole point of things like jQuery is to make things easier. I can't see the problem of using it.

Comment: so we should all program in machine language, is that what you are saying? the information might be forgotten. it is same with spoken laguages. latin is forgotten, english is now the primary language. this will happen. you can't do anything about it.

Comment: @btevfik, linguam latinam est _non_ oblitus !!

Comment: I'm not saying by any means we should all program in machine language or use pure X11 interfaces. In fact, I did my best to express how useful and good jQuery can be.

Comment: @paxdiablo name one nation that speaks latin.

Comment: @btevfik, that was meant to be humour. However, I don't consider a language dead just because no _country_ has it as an official language. There's a rather large part of Catholicism that still uses Latin and, if you know a bit, it's a heck of a lot easier to translate between any of the Latin-based languages. Still, I didn't come here to argue in comment boxes, so I'll leave it there.

Comment: What is this JavaScript you keep talking about? It's some kind of predecessor to jQuery, right?

Comment: Obligatory: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif (Extracted from previous link for immediate access to hilarity)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/122191/what-benefits-are-there-to-native-javascript-development/132357#132357

Comment: +1, I've never used jQuery, and I don't see why it's hyped. I prefer simple web designs and as few JavaScript as possible.

Comment: From what I'm personally seeing, a lot of people are "learning jQuery" and don't know how to use JavaScript. The use of jQuery is also simplifying the complex parts of scripting that need to be learned to fully understand parts of the language. People are learning shortcuts instead of learning proper usage.

Comment: @hexacyanide That's exactly the kind of thought I hoped someone would express. Think of how many sneaky errors there are in code that uses jQuery because authors don't actually understand how the jQuery really works. People say "jQuery is tested to be browser compatible" but that's only true if the one using it actually knows what it does. jQuery is not foolproof, and people don't qualify to use it if they have no clue whatsoever what it is doing. People are going to hate me for saying this, but if you don't know JavaScript, you have no business using jQuery because you don't know it either.

Comment: BTW, machine language was not a good choice of words for me to use because those words were set up as a "straw man" and attacked rather than the point I was actually making. (Straw man: A straw man argument is an informal fallacy based on misrepresenting a position so as to more easily refute it) Putting an emphasis on the importance of knowing JavaScript rather than only jQuery is not like asking everyone to learn machine language.

Comment: This isn't just limited to javascript.  A few months ago I was criticized for writing 10 lines of Socket code when I "could have used a message queue instead".  Never mind that adding a message would have required a whole new server with the associated configuration headaches, not to mention probably twice as much code to use it.

Comment: @paxdiablo the thing is sometimes, you can't use JQuery, so a JQuery answer is irrelevant and unhelpful. I am currently doing a web design project in which I am not able to use javascript, and I completely understand what this guy is talking about

Comment: Is six years later too late to point out the mistakes in the latin phrase above? ;)

Comment: As someone who's still learning JQuery, no :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

While I am a strong proponent of JavaScript education myself, and learning how to get stuff done without relying on thousands of lines of external code...

#### Let me play the devil's advocate.

Let's say you're writing an application that has to **only run on modern browsers** (old IE support is a big selling point for many) . It is **fairly simple** and **involves mainly basic dom manipulation**. I argue that as an inexperienced developer you would still be better off using jQuery. Shocked? Here is why:

1. **jQuery is *very* well documented**. Every single method in jQuery is well documented. The documentation is very good, there are plenty of examples and plenty of code demonstrating those examples. For example, a google search result for "javascript click" yields [this badly written JavaScript link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp) as the first relevant result (4th total) but "jQuery click" leads to the [this page](http://api.jquery.com/click/) which is full of useful examples
2. **jQuery makes animations easy** , it is very appealing to use jQuery to create animations, it is certainly a lot easier than to do with the DOM. You don't have to understand how stuff works to write something like `myElement.hide("fast")` and have it 'just work'
3. **jQuery makes AJAX easy** . Yes, I know AJAX is fairly straightforward in JavaScript, but `$.get` `$.load` and `$.ajax` are *very* easy to use, easier than listening to `readyStateChange` events and shorter to write. The example pages are very documented
4. **You need to know very little to get things done** . With jQuery you don't need to really understand how the DOM, stuff like event delegation are just 'done' for your ease. Sliding, toggling, adding elements, getting ancestors etc. is very easy.
5. **StackOverflow has lots of simple, short jQuery answers** A lot of times, when googling for how to do something in JavaScript a StackOverflow answer with jQuery code comes up, making solving stuff easy. We're actually *encouraging* jQuery without always meaning to.

(Plenty of other such *good* arguments, it's almost everywhere anyway, the API is easy to use and get into, plenty of cool plugins, easy support).

#### So should we encourage jQuery?

**NO** . While jQuery is a useful library, it is our responsibility as a community to encourage developers to be *better*. We're creating the next generation of our own co-workers. We should try to encourage *understanding* where we can.

So what can be done:

- When answering a jQuery question, offer an alternative JavaScript vanilla solution. Take your time to really explain it, how it works, and why. Explain how jQuery does what it does and why it might be a bad option in this case.
- When asked JavaScript questions write answers that link to good resources such as MDN, add examples and good practices. Explain why everything works. SO is in charge of a large portion of the documentation of JavaScript on the internet. It is *up to us* to make the language more accessible to people facing common problems.
- When answering AJAX question explain how and why AJAX works the way it does, why readyStateChange works the way it does and the advantages of using it. As for animations while jQuery is a good fit in a lot of these cases it is far from a silver bullet, when possible and the vanilla way is relatively short - suggest it. When it is not there are plenty of other alternative libraries that do animations
- Mention other scenarios in your answer, this will encourage the OP to try and understand why, and not just copy-(read through in the good case)-paste your code.

jQuery specific questions are *usually* (again, not always) the sign of a relatively new (again, not always) JavaScript developer. How we guide them really matters. The more we drive them towards better practices the better.

Comment: I have to partially disagree. Yes, it is kind of important that the user has a firm understanding of the underlying JavaScript, but in the particular case of JS/jQuery, seeing jQuery as a step forward, it's not *that* important. When you mention that might be effectively training our own co-workers, you forget that **you do not want** a co-worker that's good at the basics, but has no clue about anything beyond that. This is the same problem with with university people who did well in all the C/C++ exams, but have absolutely no idea how they would even begin with a non-stdlib (GUI) application.

Comment: Your answer is really great, and I accept it. What you wrote has been growing on me since the time that I asked this question. I especially like how you give the list of benefits of jQuery as the "devil's advocate," and then conclude that regardless of all those reasons, it is our responsibility to have an existence at a higher level than the comfort zone in order to deserve the freedom of enjoying the comfort zone. This answer, exactly as you wrote it, is something well worth reading for all Stack Overflow JavaScript contributors and future JavaScript developers.

Comment: *StackOverflow has lots of simple, short jQuery answers* I hope it's obvious how circular this is.

Comment: The downside is that the jQuery answers usually make the non-jQuery answers harder to find.

Comment: @dialer I agree with you & that is why I agree with this answer - as a teacher. For instance, when teaching a simple n-gram algorithm I start with simple for loops algorithm, move to using Counter, then to list comprehensions & functional methods, & finish with loading a NLP library (or sklearn depending on class). All the while asking why we are using these methods & where these could be used at work. Which is how I read this answer. That said, that's teaching not SO and it will put a lot of work on the side of the answer-er which I really don't see people doing given the state of things here

Comment: It is much easier to build code to animate things i.e:

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15521141/15893341)

Answer (score 20):

There are two kinds of programmers (no, this isn't that binary joke):

1. Those looking for the lowest effort solution.
2. Those who are mildly obsessed with finding the best solution (in pragmatic terms), and understanding why that solution works.

Changing the attitude of group #1 is a daunting task. I agree it's a problem, and it is prevalent in much more than JavaScript programming. You could make this argument about any language/platform/library, i.e. "it encourages mindless cut-and-paste, abstracts people from the 'real' issues, and builds an unbreakable dependency".

This issue reaches far beyond SO. From a SO perspective, I think the best way to counter this is to explain *why* something works, rather than spitting out a quick fix answer. There's also no harm in gently guiding people to "pure" approaches when appropriate. The [accepted answer to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript?rq=1) does just that.

Beyond that, if people want to give jQuery answers, so be it. The community is good about identifying when it does/does not make sense.

Group #2 is a completely different matter. I love jQuery not just because it made my life easier but because it emphasized how much could be done with a quirky-but-elegant language like JavaScript. I've written dozens of plugins since first using jQuery, some quite advanced. I've gone through the source code of jQuery numerous times, and dissected numerous jQuery plugins to learn more.

Many, many times, jQuery (or a similar library) is the right solution. This is a **good thing**. In the hands of a good developer, a library is a powerful tool; it enables them to produce more "goodness" faster.

Conversely, you can see that this same group of motivated engineers is still earnestly studying pure JavaScript. Browse questions around prototypical inheritance, object patterns, performance tweaks, etc. and you will see that interest in pure JavaScript is alive and well. I've been writing JavaScript for almost 15 years now, and some of the questions still are above me. I'm encouraged by that.

Comment: There is no problem with group 1! It's perfectly OK to want to know the quickest way to do something and not caring about it. Very often when coding JavaScript I look up what people did on StackOverflow just to see what alternative solutions/approaches there are. If I'm using jQuery (which is unlikely on its own) and already know how .on("click" works and I'm reading an answer using .click I don't usually need the explanation, more importantly, a lot of times people don't _care_.

Comment: I agree that is fine to look for a quick solution; I do it myself all the time and it's a great benefit of SO. In fact, part of group 2's strength is determining the most efficient way to get the job done. But if that's your whole approach to development, there's a problem. If someone knows how `click()` works, then they can skip the explanation...if they have no clue what an event is, maybe the explanation will make them think a little instead of just cutting and pasting the "magic".

Comment: The group 1 people makes me install NoScript. (Nowadays browsers are practically unusable when you have more than 5 tabs open, due to excess use of JavaScript and Flash...)

Comment: I would argue that the lowest effort solution is the best solution. Being lazy is a quality when that drives you into DRY, KISS, avoiding overdoing or over-optimizing... If jQuery saves me 10 lines of js in 2 lines of readable jQuery calls, I can't think of a good reason to go for JS.

Comment: That's practically the reason I have built a [custom CORE jQuery library support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67856386/this-undefined-via-requirejs-on-bower-and-node). You may want to try using it with your plugin to see if it works and plug your own extensions to it. :D

Answer (score 8):

This isn't a problem with SO, people just need to read the question a little more carefully. If it doesn't mention jQuery then don't answer with jQuery or if you are going to answer with it then just give reasons why you are suggesting it, e.g. "In some circumstances it allows you to only have to write 10 lines of code instead of 100."

This is also related to people trying to do everything with JavaScript instead of using the appropriate tools available to them. In particular people using [JavaScript to modify Spring forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097202/warning-request-method-get-not-supported/16097260#answer-16097239) (read the answer's editing history to see original suggestions) and do funky AJAX submissions. JavaScript is great but it is not the right tool for every occasion.

Comment: Maybe there should be a function that strips out the "jquery" string in answers, when it's not mentioned in the question :D

Comment: Thank you. This is a very good suggestion that would be well worth following. I am also looking for discussion of how we can define this boundary in our own minds, of where the dividing line is, if any, separating when to use jQuery, and when not to.

Comment: @JosephMyers, I guess that all comes down to how well you know JavaScript and its inner workings. Some people just want a quick solution and don't care how or why the jQuery works. And in the majority of cases that is what I seem to see jQuery get used for, its convenience. Everything jQuery can do, plain JavaScript can do. Probably with more efficiency for most use cases since you don't have to include a 90kB library.

Comment: @abimelex Excellent, I know a jQuery function that can do that.

Answer (score 7):

I am guilty of doing this. For the following reason:

- jQuery is pretty ubiquitous
- It does remove browser inconsistencies

Even when handling simple events (a pretty basic / common think to do) we have multiple options of syntax. Then there are questions regarding e.g Array.forEach, only in ECMAScript 5 whereas $.each is everywhere jQuery is.

It just saves us time helping the people that need help quickly without explaining these differences to them *every **single** time*.

Answer (score 2):

> How can Stack Overflow users be encouraged to use jQuery only when appropriate?

I guess it is hard to define "appropriate".

However, the [question you have shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript?rq=1) shows the best thing the community does in this area: Voting the best solution to the top.

- Answer #1 has nearly 3000 votes, and it shows the advantage of using plain JavaScript.
- Answer #2 has nearly 300 votes (only 10% of #1!), but it also tells the disadvantages of it, and in comments it is heavily discussed.

So that's what you can do: Comment answers with jQuery if you think it is "better" do be solved using pure JavaScript and why. Also post an answer where you show the advantages of pure JavaScript.

What I can see in your question is your opinion: **"People should learn JavaScript before learning jQuery!"** I don't think so. I myself started learning JavaScript and used jQuery very soon. And once you are using it longer, **and you are willing to learn**, you will also learn how the JavaScript below works.

Someone who does not care "how" it works will not learn JavaScript anyway, neither by starting using plain JavaScript first nor using jQuery first.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that the key to preserving a **solid practical benefit** to the vanilla framework is **ADAPTATION**. The reason for the millions of beginners (and even intermediate-to-advanced developers) rushing in to use jQuery is not just its documentation, although vanilla has a more solid standard community wiki at [JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) that ensures backward cross-browser compatibility than the jQuery alternative. Rather, beginners and lazy programmers concern themselves with wiki, while strong and seasoned developers rely so much on ability and proficiency with low-level custom reusable Vanilla Frameworks to mimic certain popular semantics to avoid dependencies unless necessary or demanded by the client (such as when dealing with API's).

What is missing is the transition path for beginners to become advanced developers. That said, there is so much **more wiki for the use of jQuery** than there are (if there exists) for the developer **documentation for the CORE of jQuery** that should help level up beginners from intermediate to advance paths which should put back reliance on the **Mozilla Javascript MDN**. If jQuery's core developers have invested time to document the CORE, there could have been more frameworks built than there are jQuery plugins built.

For instance, there is far too little documentation about the fact that the heart of jQuery is in the following custom code:

```
_.extend = _.fn.extend = function() {
    var target = arguments[ 0 ] || {}, options, copy,
        i = 1,
        length = arguments.length;

    if ( i === length ) {
        target = this;
        i--;
    }

    for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( ( options = arguments[ i ] ) != null ) {
            for ( name in options ) {
                copy = options[ name ];

                target[ name ] = copy;
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
};
```

So, more developers rely on using jQuery thinking the same cannot be done with their own code, perhaps believing it is the easiest way to do it because of the lack of a wiki. Plugin developers love the way jQuery offers the use of building new plugins with the following simple code without considering whether or not the same can be achieved by their own custom implementation:

```
$.extend({
    hello : function(){
        console.log('$.extending hello');
    }
});

$.hello();

$('body').extend({
    hello : function(){
        console.log('$.fn.extending hello');
        return this;
    }
}).hello();
```

Then there are others who rely on **solid vanilla** with an important intermediate understanding of more advanced topics, which is why a good [dedicated website](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) is built documenting why you might not need jQuery. There is also a good example of [building your own jQuery-like-library](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-a-jquery-like-library-in-71-lines-of-code-learn-about-the-dom-e9fb99dbc8d2/) and several other blogs that are readily accessible via Google search. These are still intermediary (as they don't include **Modular Object Semantics**, and are rather very far-fetched from the jQuery model, and just a beginner alternative, easy to copy-paste, yet HARDER TO MAINTAIN than just using jQuery. But still, **the best is in building an entirely new copycat** while at the same time far from being a jQuery fork. Nonetheless, these few examples describe an alternate, preliminary starting point, so we need such resources as these as primers to transition developers (the lazy, the novice, and the intermediate, the quick fixers) to a more advanced object oriented, practical understanding, or easy-to-grasp and portable implementation.

The present downside of jQuery is its huge dependency with [**Sizzle**](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle), a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine designed to be easily dropped into a host library, that is absent from [jQuery 1.0](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.0.js), but, that was before `querySelectors` were integrated into modern browsers, thanks to the conceptual contribution of this engine. This library though makes every new release of jQuery a tax overhead to performance.

While solid developers rely on modularity, requiring another set of skills for bundling or **including only the needed code** for **production** purposes to cost-cut-code-budget those performance issues such as by using **requirejs** with bower [as in this 2014 example](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/jquery-using-only-what-you-need), and then minifying and optimizing the result with [r.js](https://requirejs.org/docs/download.html) via node, there is still a need for full control where such things are absent from the present popular libraries as jQuery that benefit the developer to manage his own vanilla better than reading an entire jQuery handbook! I'd rather invest my time reading **MDN** than burning the candle on the jQuery oil!

Maybe other people thought that the only way to use `$` is to use jQuery, but the **Mozilla JavaScript | MDN** also uses `$` to build the community wiki without the jQuery library integrated into their [downloadable site](https://github.com/mdn/content)!

These days, it is nearly or virtually impossible to find CORE developer documentation for the jQuery library on the internet as was the case 6 or 10 years ago, maybe because by then, (if that didn't cease) people would create their own frameworks inspired by jQuery and then jQuery would not be as popular. Today, there is more documentation on HOW TO USE jQuery, besides its independent jQuery extensions/plugins that are plaguing the net away from **Vanilla MDN**, rather than **how to build libraries that can support jQuery!**

For instance, try to search Google or Stack Overflow about how to create a custom `$(this)` pure Javascript/vanilla code and you'll find that this basic, yet advanced developer question is part of the lost transition! That may change though after Google searching...

> **$(this) undefined via requirejs on bower and node**

This was my own question 6 days ago that not many developers can answer (except maybe, the jQuery core developers themselves and the smart few code diggers (working with advanced modular js out there whom I welcome to contribute their answer as well.)

What is needed, therefore, which is the missing link, is **to bridge the GAP** and promote that bridge that transitions developers to become highly advanced programmers. The fact that millions are flocking in to use jQuery and engage questions and answers to this trend is relative to the reality that there is stagnation for beginners transitioning over to quality programmers in the advanced side.

In my practical use case, (bearing other jQuery-reliant developers in mind), I have taken the liberty to codify familiar semantics, a custom vanilla CORE library built to mimic and support jQuery syntax without worrying about licenses, as a way to **ADAPT to the trending craze** while transitioning the crowd to think just a little about the portable CORE! I have been forced to rethink my own implementation (whether or not to use jQuery) for my own projects due to the new set of standard built by Facebook engineers and published in their article at [FACEBOOK Engineering](https://engineering.fb.com/2020/05/08/web/facebook-redesign/) and I have learned that I have implemented about 70-80 percent of the way Facebook does theirs with their new web version of FB, except building my own CODE-BASE since I heavily relied on jQuery for a similar use case (which the article also describes possible by using other frameworks) or needless to say, building a similar platform and also without relying on **REACTJS** but preserve the vanilla framework exclusively altogether!

The benefit is that when I started building my custom code-base, what was 7MB page is now less than 368kb resources with its un-minified library version!

I did this when I was faced with a challenge to look at how I built my code and tried the best that I can to search for proven ways, and then to make it as compliant as possible according to the most reliable source that I was able to find which is not using jQuery on a production model (Facebook's), and I was forced to look at how jQuery developers built their code, inspect several versions of the jQuery CORE down to version 1.0 prior to Sizzle, until what I was only unable to do was to **successfully find AVAILABLE SOLUTIONS** on how to change the behavior of a custom `$(this)` on my custom setup. Almost every portable solution in the net provides only for `$(selector)` but no example shows documentation on how to localize $( `this` ), because again there is little to no documentation about how jQuery is built! So I built my own code and plugged it into my previous **jQuery copycat** where I was missing only that, only to find out that `Object.assign()` and `Function.prototype.call()`, `Function.prototype.bind()` and `Function.prototype.apply()` can achieve the same thing and I found myself consequently revising to as less code as possible from the jQuery object where they miss this documentation for the following snippet for instance:

```
if(typeof selector === 'object'){

    if(selector == document || selector == window){
        if(selector===window) {
            console.log(this);
            return Array(window);
        } else if(selector == document){
            return _('html');
        }

        return _('body');
    } else {
        if(selector instanceof Element){

            this.html = function(text){
                if(arguments.length>0)
                    return selector.innerHTML = text;
                else 
                    return selector.innerHTML;
            }
            this.children = _.map(selector);

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

The more people will have access to resources such as this from a modular, **Object Semantic Model** and make them available in Stack Overflow, or other wikis, then the more people will understand how the jQuery model is built in order for themselves to build their own, without worrying about code compatibility with existing versions of the jQuery library.

So in my view, what's needed is to **promote to UNLEARN JQUERY** by re-**learning Vanilla Technology** and building **THE MISSING MANUAL** while **preserving support for jQuery**! That actually doesn't allow you to unlearn jQuery overall, but rather, that will help you achieve the balance to have a solid grasp and foundation of both jQuery and **your own Vanilla Framework** without worrying about the learning curve because people will have to worry only about ***how yours is built differently*** since you can also port their own jQuery code to yours because of the support you can choose to preserve for the jQuery Framework! Who knows, you're library may just be the next popular craze in the hood when you can build a good documentation or a wiki for your 5 kilobyte CORE! :D

Talking just about that is of no practical benefit and doesn't help a transitioning community without a working example, so here is one actual app built just for that on a 6.8kb jQuery-like code-base:

[custom CORE jQuery library support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953635/15893341).

Comment: I wonder if you are trying to make too many points at once, and thus your core point is lost in the text. Could you distil this a little bit?

Comment: Too much formatting and yelling (all caps is considered yelling in many areas of the internet).

Answer (score -4):

Could we simply tag the questions with [pure] or specifically [no-lib] when appropriate?

Also, [no-stl], [no-std], [no-boost] for c++ etc.

This could also be a new feature in SO / SE to automatically colour tags with prefix 'no-' in red.

Comment: ... just tag the question as [javascript] and not [jquery]. I for one, go ape **** ifi then see jQuery answers...

Comment: Really, meta tags? You realize we are trying to ***get rid*** of these?!