# Is it OK to promote my own code by answering my own questions?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, self-answer, self-promotion

I have written some plugins for jQuery that are very often searched on Google. One of them is used for long-click event handler, presented in a "beautiful" way, for example:

```javascript
$("a").longclick( function() { /* code */ }, 500 );
```

I want to share my work with everybody (for free). **Is it OK to post a question on Stack Overflow and answer it myself?** Or should I post somewhere else on the Stack Exchange Network?

Comment: You could create a tag and follow it. Then when you release it and people start using it, you can answer their questions for them.

Comment: You **can** write a question and answer pair, but beware - though this is technically and officially OK, many people in the community take a dim view of such self promotion, whether for profit or not.

Comment: I am mostly worried about not being downvoted for something like this!

Comment: "*I want to share my work with everybody (for free)*". Are you not sharing your work already (if it's often searched on Google)? I'm just not sure whether you're talking about using SO as a code-snippet repository here, or whether you're talking about using SO to point to your work hosted elsewhere (e.g. GitHub).

Comment: Also see [How can Stack Overflow users be encouraged to use jQuery only when appropriate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251524/how-can-stack-overflow-users-be-encouraged-to-use-jquery-only-when-appropriate). Questions and answers about a special plugin of a special library might not be very interesting and might result in only few views. Why not starting your own blog?

Comment: `written some plugins for jQuery` you should really add a tag as mentioned by BeatAlex.

Comment: You should totally drop that and try... oh wait.

Comment: I think it's okay to have a few "How I do make `longclick` (or X plugin) work with a custom function. Worst case scenario there's one of these for each plugin, but that's what would happen eventually anyway, this is just beating them to the punch

Comment: Alternatively (or worst case scenario), you can always post a link in your profile description to your github profile, or even line-by-line links to individual repositories you wish to advertise.

Comment: @Gracchus, will you upvote my code "for free"? :))

Comment: Victor, quite simply .. search on SO and you will surely find someone asking about the issue at hand. Go right ahead and answer, or better, put it in as a comment, and include a link to your web page or whatever.  By the way, **what the hell is query**??

Comment: Show HN (on Hacker News) should be a better option although I never read these posts..

Comment: SO does have a way to advertise open source projects. You could use that if it turns out your current idea isn't going to work out.

Comment: @JoeBlow, and there are [quite a bit of those questions already](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=longclick+jQuery)

Comment: Sounds like you need a blog.

Comment: yeah, but nobody will read it :))

Comment: @Victor: why have you selected John Saunders as better answer ? Tim Post post seems to be the correct answer to your question. I don't understand your choice ?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not GitHub. I recommend that you not start turning it into a code-sharing service.

Comment: Then why are we encouraged to answer our own questions? I am just trying to understand what the founders said by that :-?

Comment: Your code is not an answer. Lack of your code is not a question.

Comment: @Victor: Suppose that you discover that JavaScript behaves weirdly with the absence of semi-colons at the end of a line (`return\n"Hello, World";` and `return "Hello World";` having different behavior), then asking the question and explaining what's going on to other people will help them.

Comment: If you make a fair question SO encourages you to keep searching for the answer, not just waiting for others to find the solution. If finally you found a valid answer out of SO, you should add it to your question instead saying "Nevemind, I solved it by my own" and removing it

Comment: One of the other problems with publishing code on SO instead of GitHub (or other) is the licence. The CC licences aren't always the most appropriate for software. (If you do publish code on GitHub and have never done this before, please do remember to put a licence, otherwise we won't be able to use it.)

Comment: @PabloLozano Closing it as a duplicate is a lot better.

Comment: @JohnSaunders is spot on. Thanks for the thought, though, OP.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I'm talking about keep investigating and trying to solve an issue without SO, not looking for a similar question in SO

Comment: @Pablo then you should not remove anything but instead post the correct answer. Withholding knowledge doesn't help.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I have just seen your comment! My code in this question is not meant for being the answer. The answer would be the complete code of the plugin with some explanation on it.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Mmmh, I know my English is as good as I'd like, but that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @Pablo Oh. I understand now! Your first comment makes sense if I add "of" after "instead". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: John dude .. **"why all the anger?"**  "Stack Overflow is not GitHub." OK - who says that?  You? The founders of this business?  Is it a "general opinion" or what, buddy?  What's with the “Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style”. I see everywhere?  (is that "different"?) The only thing we know for certain about SO is: **SO is a business like Pfizer or Google started by some guys to make cash money so that they can pay for diapers and bread.** When you "recommend" that he doesn't use it as code sharing .. that's a harsh way to phrase "it would be a shame if...".  You know?

Comment: @JoeBlow Try not to confuse brevity with snark - I'm sure John didn't intend it.

Comment: Fair enough, Tim !

Comment: @JoeBlow: when I express anger, it's usually pretty clear. That's not anger, just conciseness. Besides, it doesn't even _look_ like GitHub :-). And I meant "I recommend you not start using it for code sharing, but I can't actually _stop_ you"

Comment: heh sounds great ... cheers

Comment: @JohnSaunders How does this answer reconcile with the slices of Stack Overflow's philosophy pie where it's inspired by Wikipedia and Blogging? Seems to me to be the exact use case. This way, if anyone is searching for the answers to his library, they get directed to Stack Overflow.

Comment: "IMO, the founders of SE wanted to hijack the brain of all programmers and other field experts around the world and make a super clean encyclopaedia out of it".  That's not even close. The founders of SE wanted to make money to eat - not complicated.  it would be like saying "the founders of amazon wanted to help move books around the world!!"  of course, the founders of amazon and stackoverflow wanted to: make money. To feed their children, buy diapers etc.

Comment: Why not make an article on CodeProject? You can go into more detail about your code and it could potentially see more traffic.

Comment: @JoeBlow, will I get any diapers for answering questions? Anyway, what was the question?

Answer (score 49):

We support answering your own questions, it's built right into the user interface. It's designed for those moments when you have this sort of epiphany, pull something together and want to make sure the next person finding themselves in that particular variety of quicksand is able to make use of your sage advice.

When you get into wanting to share a plugin, or entire library, it's better to just get it exposure using any of the code forges, and you *can* offer your plugin as a solution to questions where it would be appropriate. Just give *thorough* answers:

- This is mine, I wrote it
- Here is a code sample that encapsulates the example you provided
- Here's further directions you could go with it, if you wanted
- Here's (any applicable) shortcomings

I'm sure you'll find a few opportunities to do this, but make sure you answer other questions too - or folks might think you're being a bit spammy, even if it's open source (you do stand to gain contributors, but that's digressing).

I wouldn't out and out use the site as a platform to announce it, though - while I'm certain that many would appreciate it, an equal number wouldn't appreciate *how* you went about it, and would probably react negatively.

Folks have relaxed a bit when it comes to the use of the feature, but I fear this might be pushing it a tad bit far.

Comment: Nicely put. You've explained the general vibe of what is likely to happen and so on, and how that may or may not be changing over time.

Answer (score 29):

Answering questions to promote your own libraries (unless done in moderation and with the answer being useful without reference to an external resource) is likely to cause people to consider you a spammer. Creating questions that you can answer with such a promotion, more so.

Comment: Few times the same person who write answers has a 2nd account to write questions. You can easily see that by looking if answers are always to questions of the same person. Unluckily I saw that few times, and is likely that the answer from someone else will not be accepted.

Answer (score 25):

> I want to share my work with everybody (for free).

Thank you!

> Is it OK to post a question on Stack Overflow and answer it myself?

[**Yes**, definitely](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

However, you need to care about asking the correct type of question for it:

- [BAD] - *What plugin should I use for …?*

  SO is not a [recommendation service](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). `$("a").longclick( function() { /* code */ }, 500 );` would not be an acceptable answer.
- [BAD] - *What does a plugin to … look like?*

  As @JohnSaunders has very nicely put it, SO is not a code hoster. Don't paste the source of your plugin in an answer.
- [GOOD] - *How do I …?*

  You want to share your knowledge, not your plugin. Make an answer in which you outline the important techniques for …, and how to implement them. It's fine to cite relevant parts from your plugin's code for explanation purpose.

  In the end of the answer (or even in the first comment on it), you then can put *Oh and btw, I've coded this into an easy-to-use jQuery plugin here* with a link to your project's homepage.

Comment: I like this answer, it doesn't oversimplify the question. If a difficult problem is what led you to create a plugin, no reason not to share the journey with others who may run into the same thing.

Answer (score 15):

For what it's worth... my #3 most upvoted answer was a question-answer pair I wrote myself.

Ref: [On Windows 7, how does Java JVM set "user.home" System property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889940/on-windows-7-how-does-java-jvm-set-user-home-system-property/16889969#16889969)

I spent far too long on this problem.  When I found the solution after very tough Googling, I wanted to share with others.  StackOverflow did not have the answer.  Admittedly, I felt awkward the first time.  After I got votes on both sides (Q & A), I've done a few more.

I do this when an answer requires me to synthesize multiple, diverse sources: Google, official docs, source code, blogs, and StackOverflow.

Answer (score 12):

I think if you can formulate a good question, then give a good answer that includes your code, that is quite acceptable. However, if the question you give is "how do I do X beautifully", that is not acceptable. Make sure the question is something people actually ask, and represents a real problem.

Also, make sure the answer includes the code, don't link to your own website or blog. As long as the question is useful, and as long ad your answer is well written and includes your code, you should have no problems.

Comment: Once framed as a question, it may turn out that it's been already asked. Checking for that should also be part of the process.

Comment: `Make sure the question is something people actually ask, and represents a real problem.` Wow, is that hair splitting.  People will up- and down- vote for a variety of reasons -- but self-promotion is one of those things that can get you down-voted into oblivion if it's too obvious.

Answer (score 11):

You could create a question at [**Software Recommendations** SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (tagged with [jquery](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery)) and answer it yourself, either including the full code (if it’s short) or linking to it. Make sure to [disclose](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/407/60) that it’s your software.

(You could also post a question with your code (or several questions about specific parts of your code, if it’s too long) at [**Code Review** SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), asking for improvements.)

Note that any code you post on the SE network will be licensed under [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). But you can, of course, license it under other licenses in addition, e.g., you could say that your code is *also* licensed under GPLv3 or that it’s in the public domain.

Answer (score -10):

As a newbie to this site I'd have to say I wouldn't care if the answer was self-answer/promotion as long as it solved a problem or gave me insight to a problem.

Comment: It's ok if you don't care. There are those of us who will care on your behalf, so you don't have to.

Answer (score -16):

Yes it is now possible. StackExchange has added a new CheckBox to indicate that the Question contains an Answer.

You can find more information on this page:

[https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Thanks to all guys that have contributed to push this new enhancement.

Comment: That blog post is from 6 years ago, so it's not a "new enhancement". You were always able to self-answer. This isn't what the question is asking.

Comment: this seems to merely repeat point made (and much better explained) in at least two prior answers that were posted several years ago, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255695/839601) and especially [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256405/839601)

Comment: Ok, the link is old but this link is not referenced in this post and it explain clearly what to do.

Comment: And what about the CheckBox "Answer your own question" just below "Post your question" button. It is new or not ?

Answer (score -19):

I think that posting an article that exposes a problem and explains directly the solution is a good thing.

Posting a question and posting immediately the response is only a workaround.

Suppose that you search to resolve a problem and that you find yourself a solution. You can post a question and then answer to it in another post... with the risk that after a long time your response's post is separate from your question.

**What is missing is StackExchange is the possibility to post an article without question.**

Somebody has alreay posted a question about that but the post is locked
[Where can I post a complete solution I found, as an “article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269718/where-can-i-post-a-complete-solution-i-found-as-an-article)

I don't know the author of this post, but I find interesting to reopen it because this post is distinct from this.

There exists a difference between asking to post directly an article and asking to answer to proper question.

The second question is a bad workaround of the first !

I don't understand why StackExchange doesn't encourage writing articles (not posting code, only writing article).

I thought that the purpose of StackExchange is to encourage users to share their knowledge !

Is "writing directly an article" not sharing knowledge ?

Comment: The SE network of sites tries to be good at being a Question and Answer site. That means we explicitly stay away from blogs/articles/forum like threads. There are plenty of other sites that cater for that. On SE contributions simply has to follow the Q/A pattern. Nothing is *missing*, it doesn't exist by design.

Comment: The right question is . "What is the purpose/goal of StackExchange". Is there to promote sharing of knowledge as written in his About page OR Question and Answer as already written in his About page. I'm analyst and "Question&Answer" is not a goal, it is a concept. I have no problem with that and I will write all my articles on CodeProject even if this can be interesting to share with your users because you don't accept my point of view.

Comment: @schlebe we have our way of doing things (Q&A style) and other sites have their own ways of doing things. We are not obliged to host every bit of content that you think might be useful. If you don't want to make the content fit within the construct provided for you, that's your choice, but we are not going to change the construct to fit your content. Our construct works for us, and we are very heavily invested in the continuation of said construct at this point.

Comment: @Tiny: I don't want to change the construct to fit my content because posting a message that is an article and not a question is already possible ! I can create a post and write in the title that this post is an article and other persons can react to my article as it is a question. What I want is that the first post can be categorized not as a question but as an article and that this practice (already possible) is accepted as a correct practice.

Comment: @schlebe that would be changing the construct.

Comment: @TinyGiant: the following link https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference is an article posted by StackOverflow as a question ... but this is an article ! I want to do as StackOverflow, posting an article without question and let others users post "response". StackOverflow make that ! Why not us ?

Comment: @schlebe meta site are different than the main sites. They are much more relaxed in many ways.

Comment: @all - thanks to StackExchange that has finally added the possiblity to flag question as a question/answer like described in my post. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ It is very disturbing to have a lot of negative points when my request is finally implemented :-)

Comment: @schlebe that is not a new feature, has been around since 2011. That checkbox does not exempt your question from the requirement of being in the form of Q&A, and historically such Q&A sets are subject to a much greater level of scrutiny than normal Q&A sets.