# User promoting his software in relevant questions without disclosure

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I was searching for DiagramO, an open source  diagramming software on Stack Overflow. In its search results almost all the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=diagramo%20is%3Aanswer) are written by a single user, who is the creator of the software according to his profile without any disclaimer about it being his software in his answers. I recall reading that when promoting your own software you need to have a disclaimer in your post.

I went through most of the questions for those answers and they are mostly about recommending a drawing tool. So his answers are relevant to the questions and some of them are up-voted and accepted. The user has also contributed to other questions.

So should I flag the answers as spam or should I comment on them asking to add disclaimer to the answer  or should I report about the user?

Comment: First answer I found was `Check Diagramo. It might fit your needs.`  I don't care how much rep you have, that's an undisclosed affiliation and looks like spam to me.  I'm hesitant to go flag-crazy in this case since there's so many answers; a single "Other" flag fully describing the situation is probably sufficient, but now that it's on Meta, it'll probably get more attention that way too.

Comment: The true problem is the nature of the questions that those answers appear on.  They should **all** be closed, frankly.

Comment: Yeah I thought about the questions the same and have flagged some of the questions as recommending a software or primarily opinion based and run out of flags

Comment: He's losing a lot of rep today because of this.

Comment: As well he should.  I'm bummed I'm out of delete votes for the day already, otherwise I'd be popping those closed questions.

Comment: Rep was not my primary concern it was following the rules and disclosing that he is the creator of the software.

Comment: Someone should let Alex know what's going on.  He may not be aware of the requirements for self-disclosure.  Took me several minutes to find it.

Comment: @james.garriss - I'm sure a moderator will be in touch with him, considering a moderator deleted three-fourths of his answers

Comment: Before everyone piles on this poor guy, let's give him the benefit of the doubt and assume he meant well but went about things in the wrong way. He's now been provided with the site's self-promotion guidelines. Most authors of open source projects I've interacted with for things like this simply were excited and proud of their project, and wanted to let people know about it. They weren't aware of site policies and corrected their posting behavior immediately after being warned. I'm willing to believe that's the case here.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson and the SO community for taking care of the issue and I feel exactly the same about the user

Comment: @BradLarson:  I have no qualms around the user's intentions whatsoever.  It's the *questions* that personally made me rage.

Comment: @BradLarson I now see some of the questions were deleted and some are closed. Where can I find the guidelines about when a question is deleted and when it is closed as they all seem to me as asking for a recommending a software.

Comment: @Sri You might want to look at a few help center links to help you out. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) is about closed questions, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) handles deletion. A lot of the ones I looked at earlier were indeed software recommendation, which is off-topic as I'm sure you already know.

Comment: The user in question is moderately high rep -1054- they should know better than to spam.

Comment: I run an open source project that provides project templates (scaffolding) and graphical designers for Windows Installer XML.  I often get WiX questions from people who are starting from step 1 and stumbling.  Is it really spam for me to suggest that my open source project might help them get off the ground?  I try to always remember to say that it's my open source project but sometimes I'm in a hurry and forget.   If I mention it, it sounds promoting, if I don't it comes off as deceptive.

Comment: Last month I felt [this question/self-answer pair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223707/create-pdf-files-with-javascript) was bordering on self promotion but couldn't decide what to do with it.

Comment: @Jongware Just flag it as other and explain it to the moderator. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255509/2246380) question about promoting once code by self answering

Comment: @Jongware The user seems to have copied the content for [that self answering question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28223707/2246380) from [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23667204/2246380) to his [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21060876/2246380) looks so strange

Comment: @ChristopherPainter, better to be honest and sound like a pompous ass than to deceive and be one.

Comment: @Makoto that's a very good point - **[questions asking for diagram tools](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdiagram%5D+closed%3Ano+tool)** look like a huge broken window. No wonder that user fell through it so badly. I complained about these questions to [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: @gnat - and there went my 50 close votes for the day ;)

Comment: @Sri - and then the submitter of *that answer* (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23667204/334849) posted links to their product in three other answers, two of which don't disclose their affiliation to the product.  It's a vicious cycle...

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables that's very nice of you, because I spent about 30 votes planned to these for today on a bunch of "your" _looking-for_ questions that were at risk of votes expiry :)

Comment: @gnat - so many questions, so few votes ;)

Comment: [We need more close votes!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285438/839601) ;)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I think the affiliation  is not very clear in that answer itself except the word "my". I did flag some of the users posts.

Comment: "**I went through most of the questions ... and they are mostly about recommending a drawing tool.**" I'm confused. Questions asking for tools recommendations are close-worthy, aren't they?

Comment: Wow, this is exactly the type of attention I would want if I wrote that software.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes they should be closed but unfortunately weren't and there are lot more question need be closed like mentioned by [gnat](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285851/user-promoting-his-software-in-relevant-questions-without-disclosure?noredirect=1#comment154387_285851)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think it's important to be clear what the problem exactly is here.  It's not that he wrote the software and that he's referring to it in his answers; it's that **[he's not disclosing that he wrote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), and the quality of his "answers" on these questions is very low.** e.g.

> - [Check Diagramo It is only HTML5 and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15570373/1612701)
> - [Check diagramo It's JavaScript/HTML5 and GPL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13967367/1612701)
> - [Check diagramo Easy to use, HTML5 and open sourced.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335967/1612701)
> - [Another one might be diagramo: html5, opensource and commercial use.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14727421/1612701)

Those are the *entire answers* to four different questions.  They could have been acceptable if the answers had been more full and had a disclaimer that said something like "disclaimer: I am the author of diagramo."

And then there's the separate issue that *all* of these questions are software recommendations, which are off topic on Stack Overflow.

An example of a user who does this correctly is [maximus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405560/maximus).  He wrote [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), a console emulator for Windows.  His answers are never link-only answers, he's active on the tag, and he discloses that he's the author whenever he recommends the software.

Check out Brad Larson's answer for [recommending your own open source libraries in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229085/how-to-offer-personal-open-source-libraries/229091#229091) for more info on the right way to go about mentioning your personal projects on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Here's the Help Center page that talks about self disclosure:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Thanks for the like @james.garriss.  I added the link to the answer.

Comment: He does reveal that he's the developer in his profile.  But I suppose thats a bit too hidden away.

Comment: See also:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/what-signifies-good-self-promotion-or-self-promotion-part-infinity.  Self-promotion on SO is a very tricky thing to do right.

Comment: In the specific case of promoting open source libraries that you're involved with, I elaborate on how you can provide answers without being too spammy here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229085/how-to-offer-personal-open-source-libraries/229091#229091

Comment: There are situations where certain software authors are sufficiently well known in their language communities that it seems less important to be explicit about disclosure (as most people reading will *know* that they wrote the software in question). But generally, yes, disclosure is essential.

Comment: More examples of how to "correctly promote" your product or library on Stack Overflow by high rep and insanely high rep users: [LINQPad](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A46223+%5Blinqpad%5D) and [protobuf-net](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A23354+%5Bprotobuf%5D). Actually, this is not really promotion but more a kind of support.

Answer (score 17):

This appears to be blatant self promotion.

I would flag one of the answers for a moderator's attention, explaining that many answers written by him fall into this category. They can probably deal with it most efficiently.

Comment: With hindsight, this would have been the right move; as in the last few hours he's had a lot of his lost reputation restored as 'reversal of serial downvoting'.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that there is a little war started by "Sri" on some of my posts.

I think that because I use Stack Overflow to some degree I must answer to those that might want to know the case.

Yes, I started Diagramo, yes, and I advised people to take a look at it in case they might need it.

I started Diagramo when [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) emerged and where there was almost no similar stuff, so *yes*, I'm proud of making something like that...and maybe "praise" it a little bit.

I do not know what "Sri" is doing and could be very well someone from a similar tool taking dirty tactics...I don't even bother study this...I will let other study this aspect....I do coding, not forensics.

It is written in my short "bio" that I initiated the Diagramo project - nothing is hidden.

I even wrote in some of my Diagramo related posts that I contribute to Diagramo - again not hiding anything. Not at all - that seems to be my own "death penalty" mistake. **I didn't do that on purpose**.

**Do not worry, I will mention it from now on**, and I'm actually very proud to do it....but I will not go back in time to change my already posted questions.
Some of those questions are closed anyway.

Please go ahead and do whatever you want with my reputation (to which I frankly do not care too much) and my post but at least keep the reference to Diagramo which a lot of people (MIT included) find it vital for their (coding) life.

I hope that this post make clear my intention.

p.s. Ah! I almost forgot. **Disclosure**: *As I mentioned Diagramo in this post I need to mention that I sometimes proudly contribute to it*

Comment: I think that the fact you mention in your profile that you are associated with Diagramo has gone against you which I believe is really sad.

Comment: I was using DiagramO and thought It was a great software and was looking if it has for its presence in SO and saw your posts with not disclosure and wanted to know if they are following the [SO rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) and posted the question to clarify what needs to be done. I have never proposed in  my posts to do something against you I was just checking if your post were following the rules. I frankly don't the skill set to design such a good software and  I am not working for any other tool competing tool.

Comment: "I will mention from now on" -- Great!  You're cool.  I am concerned that you talk about "I will not go back .. to change my already posted questions".  Did you really mean answers?  Or have you been posting questions just so you can answer saying how great your tool is?  Assuming you mean answers, then you don't have to change anything except disclosing your connection every time you suggest your software (if someone has already found your software and asked for help using it, then disclosure is a good idea but not mandatory)

Comment: @Alex If I were you I'd just delete this answer and forget about it completely mate (no need to get forensic and its very clear you were not hiding anything and now know *the policy* to put disclaimers in answers).

Comment: @JeremyThompson thank you for your kind answer :)

Answer (score -12):

Don't get me wrong but I personally I feel that user is being singled out because of the meta effect and almost all the questions he answered are relevant answers and are for recommending a tool kind of questions and most of the questions have other one line answers which are upvoted. I found out this user because he disclosed it in his profile. The other users who answered could have been the developers of the respective software with no disclosure at all.

Hence I feel deleting the questions itself or deleting all the answers is more justified than just deleting this user's answers.

Comment: In that case don't single out users in meta questions. Flag for moderator attention instead, or just focus on the questions themselves.

Comment: The [help center explicitly states](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) "you _must_ disclose your affiliation in your answers". He's not doing it.  He should be flagged.  If other people are guilty they should get flagged too.  Just because we haven't caught all the murderers doesn't mean they should all go free.

Comment: @Bart There are more than 50 related questions to be flagged hence I wrote the question on meta

Comment: You can always use the "other" flag and point out "hey, this users is exaggerating the self-promotion a bit". One flag, 50 birds.

Comment: Sure that and also the questions need to be flagged as being unfit for stackoverflow.

Comment: most of the questions from your original list are already dealt with (closed, some deleted) As far as I can tell, only about 10 of original 50 remain open, and most of these are on their way to close

Comment: If a user didn't earn the reputation legitimately, then why should you feel any sort of remorse?  We all have to abide by the same rules.

Comment: Welcome to meta, there's always a witch to be burned, and if there's not, the burners are sure to find one.

Comment: The user in question has a little under 1.1k reputation, they should know better, and I certainly have *very little* sympathy for them regarding the Meta effect.

Comment: True, The user had around 1.6k rep before I posted the question.

Comment: @Becuzz I think likening attempting to help people on Stack Overflow to committing murder is a poor analogy.

Comment: @DavidWallace I was using a bit of hyperbole to make a point.  The point wasn't to say that doing something wrong on SO was akin in severity to committing murder.  The point was to illustrate that we don't give everyone a free pass merely because someone somewhere hasn't been caught doing the same thing.