# What is the policy regarding sparse self-promotion in answers?

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion

I am aware of [the policy regarding self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) in answers; the author of an answer is required to disclose affiliation with any links given when appropriate.

However, what if the self-promotion is sparse to begin with?  What if it didn't exist prior to the single answer in which it occurred?

Further, what if the name on the repository matches the name of the author?

For example, a company named "Initech" posts an answer with a link to `https://github.com/initech`, but "Initech" isn't in the link text and there is no mention of affiliation; is this still not allowed?  Of course, the prior example would also apply to individuals, but the question remains the same; what should be done here?

Comment: If someone is actively trying to hide their affiliation (and it's pretty easy to tell if they are), that's pretty damning IMO.

Comment: Good question! I recently had a discussion with a user whose opinion was that his name on the github repo was enough disclosure, and that stating that he created the code was just noise and extra self promotion. I'd like the opinion of the community on this issue (essentially your situation except he wasn't hiding the link in formatting, that's just noise in this question)

Comment: @BoltClock A self-promotion "masked" like [this](http://stackoverflow.com) doesn't seem like an intentional attempt to hide anything, more like an attempt at formatting properly combined with a bit of ignorance about the disclosure requirement.

Comment: Uh-oh, I think Initech slipped a link into your question, disguised in a code block!

Comment: As far as the answer is good, who made it may not be critical.

Comment: Didn't have the guts to post the answer (it would have been my first on MSO) but I'll post my main point as a comment: For me the bottom line is not what "sparse" is but what "self-promotion" is.

Comment: What do you mean by "mask"ing the link?

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not sure how else it can be interpreted, but I specifically mean using formatting so it isn't a straight link.  https://google.com vs [some site that is relevant to the answer](https://google.com).

Comment: @Daedalus: ...you call that masked? I would not have guessed. I thought you meant concealing the link entirely, not just providing meaningful link text instead of a raw URL.

Comment: @Daedalus: What sarcasm?

Comment: @user2357112 Since that does not qualify as masking, what wording would you use?  And for the example in the question, it isn't that the text is meaningful; the example I gave in comments is a bad one, but I don't know how else to word linking text in a manner which does not relay the site's name or origin.

Comment: I'd word it something like "a company named "Initech" posts an answer with a link to https://github.com/initech, but with link text that doesn't say "initech" anywhere, and with no other explicit mention of affiliation."

Comment: @user2357112 I attempted to edit according to your suggestion.

Comment: @Dukeling: Yeah, that seems rather innocuous, and it might be what this is referring to after all, rather than something more sly such as "I found this library [link to library that's actually mine and not just something I found]"

Comment: “Sparse” appears to be the wrong word for what you’re asking, no? I think you’re just trying to say “not fully disclosed”?

Comment: @deceze Sparse, as in reference to how often the event has occurred in answers.

Comment: I think a link to a git repo or a specific piece of code/information in that repo doesn't count as book/product/site promotion in the first place. But it has to comply with *"Don't include links except to support what you've written.*", so if you have an answer saying *"your problem could be solved by calling the api like this: `small(but).complete->snippet;`, see [this class](http://github.example.com/GolezTrol/awesome.asm) for a more elaborate example on how to use it"*, then I think there's not much wrong with that, regardless who originally put that class on Github.

Comment: @GolezTrol: If it's your repo or you're a contributor to it, it is (IMHO). It's not hard to avoid the appearance of impropriety: *"...see this class [I'm a maintainer on that repo] for a more elaborate..."* (or via a footnote as shown in my answer if it makes the text too awkward). (Agreed that links must only support the answer.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Of course, it's not hard, but I wouldn't consider omission to be an attempt to hide affiliation. I tend to lean to the opinion of that user that Erik von Asmuth commented about: a matching name already provides some disclosure, and if the repo is some public domain piece of code, explicitly mentioning that I was the original author might just add extra noise. I probably would add it, because I love taking credit :p , but I wouldn't think anything bad of people who don't. Only if there is some commercial background there, then I would expect more explicit disclosure.

Comment: @GolezTrol: *"I probably would add it, because I love taking credit :p"* **:-D**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User promoting his software in relevant questions without disclosure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285851/user-promoting-his-software-in-relevant-questions-without-disclosure)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't over-think it. :-) From [the help page you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion):

> ...you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.

That's quite clear. If you're linking to your own product, site, content, etc., **say so**, clearly. Don't expect me to infer it by correlating your username with something in the link (or its text). And don't forget that if you change your username, and were relying on that correlation in some answers three years ago, you'll suddenly start breaking the rule on disclosure. So just say so in the text. Simple. It's an easy rule to understand, and an easy rule to explain.

It isn't noise, and it doesn't have to get in the way. You can even footnote it.

Example:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua [Super-Whiz-Library](http://example.com).¹ Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
>
> ---
>
> ¹ *(I'm one of the maintainers of that library)*

Comment: Too official. Possessive pronouns are shorter and works too.

Comment: @Sinatr: Absolutely. If it works to write "...my [Super-Whiz-Library](http://example.com)...", that's perfectly clear.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you defend this point: "If you're linking to your own product, site, content, etc., **say so**, clearly."? Perhaps it's good etiquette to do so, but *in general*, I think this is a bit extreme. I don't see how this is a sufficient condition for spam. Take the disagreement happening [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368887/why-did-i-fail-this-lqprq-audit) - the answer is spam according to the page you linked to. But I don't think it fits the conventional definition.

Comment: @pushkin - The help page linked at the top of the answer above says *"...and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."* The answer in the question you've asked doesn't do so. It needs to, that's the site's policy. I'm not going to get into a debate over the precise meaning of "spam," but that's the site's policy.