# Why did I fail this LQPRQ audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19892209) Low Quality Posts review audit, but I'm not sure why. Here is the answer:

> `// calling action
>   var executeAction = orgService.Execute(
>       new OrganizationRequest("new_GreetAction") {
>           Parameters = {
>               { "InArg", "Ashish" }
>           }
>       });`
>   Use it this way
>   https://www.ashishvishwakarma.com/executing-actions-using-javascript-c-sharp-example-dynamics-365/

Though I'm not *super* familiar with the topic, and this isn't necessarily a high-quality post, I don't understand why it was deleted.

According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) post, answers shouldn't be deleted just because they're low quality. They should be deleted if they're not answers (or they're link-only answers).

The "Recommend Deletion" options are:

- This is commentary on another post, not an answer - nope
- This is a "thank you" comment - nope
- This is an "I'm having this problem, too" comment - nope
- This is a different question posted as an answer - nope
- This is a link-only answer (and not spam) - nope

It may not be the *correct* answer, but it's not one for which I should recommend deletion. Am I in the wrong?

I'm particularly salty, because now I've been banned from the review queues for two days.

Comment: i mean... because the audit wanted you to do something other than the action you took? i wouldn't suggest spending too many cycles worrying about it. Reviewing is subjective, there's bound to be audits that are borderline.

Comment: A red flag is that the linked site name is identical to the username. That's a big warning for spam. There's one important delete option you didn't list: no comment needed, which is the appropriate one for spam. You could argue the answer could be salvaged by removing the link, and including the linked parts, but the author should at least have disclosed before linking to his own blog.

Comment: @KevinB I get that it's subjective in some ways, but doesn't this answer blatantly not fit any of the criteria in the Recommend Deletion popup?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I agree that it's a warning for spam, but I wouldn't say that it is in this case. Sure maybe they could have mentioned that it was their blog, but regardless of whether or not they mention it, it's not technically spam

Comment: The post is crapvertisement for a blog. Maybe it's not "technically spam" - I don't know what the governing standard is for technically qualifying something as such. You admit yourself that it is poor quality. The point of review queues is to keep crap out.

Comment: @Mat "The point of review queues is to keep crap out." - Agreed. So would you recommend that I disregard the standards laid out in the linked meta post?

Comment: I suggest you use your judgement and skip if you're unsure. If you think a post is a positive contribution to SO, review as such. If you think it shouldn't be on SO, review as such. If you fail an audit once in a while, well, that's life. Don't say the post looks ok if you think it's crap.

Comment: @Mat I'm less concerned with the fact that I failed an audit and more concerned with the fact that I was banned from the review queues for two days. "Don't say the post looks ok if you think it's crap" - I suppose I agree. I'll skip next time. Though it seems that there's a lot of contradictory info out there regarding when "Looks OK" should be used.

Comment: @pushkin It's not "not technically spam".  The *definition* of spam on the site includes, among other things, not properly disclosing your affiliation to a product you're referencing, so it *is* technically spam.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion

Comment: @Servy That's an odd definition for spam... (though that warrants another question).

Comment: This answer has validated spam flags on it (deleted by a moderator), so it qualifies as a review audit. I also agree that this post is spam.

Answer (score -1):

Because spam, not the one that is a digestible sustenance. While [I'm against those post used by audits on that queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238647/213575), since I know those appear as audits, I know how to evade them.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. It's all well and good that you know how to evade audits, but I was questioning the very premise that the post is spam. From the comments, it looks like the answer is basically that [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) define this post as spam.

Comment: @pushkin you say that you "don't understand why it was deleted", this answer tells you why. You ask "Am I in the wrong?" I say "I'm against those post used by audits on that queue".

Comment: Nevermind, I was confused. So your stance is that it *is* spam, but it shouldn't have been an audit. Thanks