# Multiple answers in a short time that may fall foul of the "disclosing affiliation" rules

Tags: discussion, spam, self-promotion

<sup>Preamble: I don't think it's a duplicate of the suggested "what is the policy regarding self-promotion?" as that deals more with one's self keeping within affiliation rules, whereas this is more about how to fix self-promotion by others - reasons outlined in the last paragraph</sup>

I was recently looking for a way to do something, browsed and found a few useful resources on Stack Overflow, including a couple of similar looking questions. I noted that both those questions had an answer posted that was similarly (though not identically) worded at a similar time, and the answers were referencing a particular GitHub repo, the owner of which had the same name as the user's username on the site.

I did a quick search on SEDE and turned up around 5 answers, all worded slightly differently, over maybe a half hour period on a particular day, with some handful of other similar answers over the course of the rest of the membership (and plenty of answers unrelated, so they are/were quite contributory in other ways).

The answers themselves were essentially a basic code sample (~5 lines) for how to use the lib, usually tweaked slightly in the context of question, and a bit of a "check this lib out on [link to GitHub], it can do what you want" phrase. The library is dual licensed GPL/commercial.

All in all, I'd say this is undisclosed affiliation - perhaps not the worst case we'll have seen but I did reach out to the author concerned and pointed out that I felt they should disclose their affiliation on their posts about this particular lib. I haven't seen any subsequent edits to any answers, so I'm asking if I should follow it up and if so, in what way? I have sufficient rep, patience and SEDE abilities to identify all the candidate posts and edit in a footnote so I perhaps don't need to bother a moderator with it, but equally that might be perceived by the author as quite hostile, something that might come over better from someone with more authority. If it should be reported, how best to raise it and give the mod team the complete picture? Flag every answer? Flag one and put a SEDE query in the flag reason?

Comment: There's indeed no need to discuss the particulars of the user, or their answers; asking a general question is much more preferable when possible. Thank you for not linking to any of that content.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the policy regarding sparse self-promotion in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361284/what-is-the-policy-regarding-sparse-self-promotion-in-answers)

Comment: @gnat Thanks, that helps - don't think it's 100% a duplicate; I'm reasonably comfortable that I've identified a case that would be deemed self promotion, be it dense, sparse or somewhere on the spectrum. I'm interested to know what I should do about it. I have sufficient rep to direct edit their answers or post a comment highlighting affiliation, I can find the answers with SEDE etc.. I did feel it should come from compelling the author to see the same way or bringing in a more authority figure than me so as not to trigger a backlash..

Comment: Maybe is relevant to check if that specific user just wanted to improve his/her reputation by posting so much / so fast, as for achieving here some more privileges (to comment, to edit other people's posts, etc)

Comment: If the answers are substantially similar, wouldn't the proper thing to find the best question/answer pair and mark the others as duplicates?

Comment: @Flydog57 Assuming they're duplicates, yes, though it's common for people to search for questions their tool can solve and then present similar answers on all of them suggesting their tool. They're rarely duplicates, it's more akin to spam, but if done correctly it's acceptable here.

Comment: Some of the questions could reasonably be marked as duplicates, but lets say this is an astro library that calcs a lot of different things - the answers are applicable to each of the different questions, but a "how to convert from AU to Lmn?" isn't a duplicate of "how to calculate when Mars was coming into Venus, back in 1969?" ;)

Comment: over the course of time i have to certain questions similar answers, that is normalm if you are budy on one tag. but when if he hasn't disclosure his affiliation it is clearly spam

Answer (score 22):

If a user has a bunch of contributions that are not promoting their own product, with only a few instances that mention the product, then it's not something I would consider as Spam (i.e overt self-promotion). However, disclosing affiliation in the answer is still mandatory if the question doesn't ask about the product directly.

You did the right thing by reaching out to the user and asking them to add in disclosure. You can wait for a couple of days for the user to add in the disclosure on their own, but after that, you can go ahead and flag one of the user's posts with links to the answers that don't disclose affiliation. This is especially true if the user has been active since you left the comment. That means they've chosen to ignore your comment, which then requires a moderator to step in to make the policy clear to the user.

In cases where you see only a single instance of a user mentioning their product without disclosing affiliation, you can also go ahead and edit in disclosure in addition to leaving a comment. Then I would suggest following the answer, and if the user ever rolls back the edit (or otherwise removes the disclosure), go ahead and raise a custom flag to inform a moderator about the issue.

Comment: 5 self-promotion answers in 30min that do not disclose the affiliation and do not actually answer the question concretely? I would definitely consider that to be spam. Downvote and flag.

Comment: @Bergi The proportion of self-promotional answers does make a difference. If it's 5/5, or even 5/10, I would call that spam, but if it's more like 5/100 (which is the impression I get from the OP's phrasing) then it's ok. I don't think the time frame is too important, either. Also, I get the impression that the answers *were* relevant to the question, and the only issue was the lack of disclosure.

Comment: I don't think the timescale is relevant. Perhaps the user over a period of years saw there were a lot of unsolved problems in the field, realised that what people needed was a library that solved the problems, finally one weekend got down to writing the library, put it on GitHub, and then told all those users about its existence? Not exactly a crime, is it?

Comment: It's not the proportion but only the number of promotional answers to me. I'm not trying to judge the account as a spammer, and I wouldn't want them to get banned, but these 5 answers should be flagged and deleted. One or maybe two answers? That's fine, the user might have come across the question and wanted to leave a link to their library, in which case the should get a comment on adding disclosure. But five answers? That's *active promotion*, they must have been searching for these questions, a behaviour which is clearly prohibited.

Comment: @MichaelKay If the user spent years on StackOverflow, I'd expect them to know what a good answer is and what a link-only answer is. Leaving a comment "*My library xyz could help you here*" might be ok-ish, but an answer should actually answer the question. I don't know the posts the OP is talking about, but "*a basic code sample (~5 lines) and link to GitHub*" does not sound like an answer to me, especially if only a generic readme code sample. If they really spent a weekend on it, they should have been able to spend some time writing concrete code examples that answer each concrete question.

Comment: @Bergi Don't assume that the longer someone is on StackOverflow, the more compliant they become in doing what the rules say you should do. I have a 50-year career in programming and I have always made my own choices about which rules to follow and which to ignore.

Comment: If it helps, the questions are something like "how do I convert astronomical units to lightminutes, Foxpro doesn't have anything built in" and the answers can be fairly cookie cutter "The [foxtronomy](http://github.com) library can do this for you. `x = CreateObject('Foxtronomy')` `x.AuToLightMin(1234)`

Comment: @MichaelKay I'm not saying they would become more compliant, but at least they should be more familiar with the rules :-) Either way, I don't think it matters how long the user was active on SO (or not). 5 fast-paced promotional answers should be flagged and deleted if they come from *any* account. For a new user (if those are their only posts), it's just more likely that the entire account gets suspended.

Comment: @CaiusJard So it's actually `x.AuToLightMin(1234)`, answering the question, not a "*foxtronomy can convert any unit to any other, for example `x.CubicFeetToSphericalCows(123)`*"? Then I'm more happy about it, and wouldn't spam-flag, but [still expect them to disclose their affiliation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361284/what-is-the-policy-regarding-sparse-self-promotion-in-answers).

Comment: The questions I've checked aren't "how do I convert 1234 au to lmn" they're perhaps more like "how do I convert au to lmn" - some questions do have "how do I convert au to lmn for example I'm expecting 2345 au to come out as 6789 lmn" and the code sample doesn't use the example 2345 given, but generally if it's a question about astronomical X the code sample refers to X, Y to Y, so in essence the samples are adjusted relevantly. I don't think it's particularly underhand.. it just feels like there could be ample opportunity to even just stick a "my library X" in and it doesn't happen..

Comment: No. The timescale is irrelevant. Something I've done before is search for a common typo and fix it. What this user's done could be, search for a common problem and address it by answering the questions.

Comment: @OmarL A proper way to have gone at this would have been to answer only one of the questions, then close the other ones as duplicates of the most viewed / general one.