# Promoting company through (technical) SO posts

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I browse and read questions on Stack Overflow quite a bit in my spare time. I have started to notice [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357441) who has been doing large 'drops' of self-answered questions.  Answers typically come within a minute of the question:

[image: user posts]

It is fine to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but in this case it is obviously done to gain exposure for a commercial organization.  All the questions and answers relate to one company.

[This thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255509/is-it-ok-to-promote-my-own-code-by-answering-my-own-questions) shows that the SO community takes a dim view of doing this to promote your own code libraries, so why is this allowed to continue to promote exposure for a commercial company on Stack Overflow?

Comment: They look broadly on-topic to me. None of the posts appear to be *promoting* a service, so much as suggesting solutions for problems some *who happen to already be using the service* might encounter. Do you see any posts recommending "Use/buy <some service> that you aren't already using"? I don't. Documenting common problems for a particular service on Stack Overflow, while not entirely *usual*, is different from *promoting* the service, so I think it's OK.

Comment: That's probably material for a mod flag and not for a Meta discussion. If you have sufficient reasons to believe they are *violating* something (for example, not disclosing affiliation) and spotted a pattern, it is better to let those whose day-to-day is to handle such things, not leave it to the crowd (us) to lynch the user. A quick look through their profile and posts you mentioned does not reveal anything particularly malicious about their intentions. And I think Huawey is no need for forced exposure via SO. The links also point to the official developer website and to actual docs at that.

Comment: I honestly don't see any problem with the MO. The user seems to focus on [answering questions related to Huawei Mobile Services](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14357441/zinna?tab=answers&sort=votes) and also including related official documentations (good!) without promoting the service. Whether it's someone who has long experience with it, or even Huawei staff, I don't see the problem. Even if it's the latter, I think we should appreciate them [that they monitor SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support), unlike many other products...

Comment: As CertainPerformance said, as long as the post is on-topic, not a duplicate, and not actually promoting something, I don't see any problem with it. Whether it's one, 10, or 1000 questions, it doesn't matter. The _only_ situation that might be problematic, in my opinion, is if they post a large number of posts in a short period of time resulting in flooding the home page with said posts (which doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: @Andrew T does dumping a question and answer onto the site really equate to "monitoring the site"?  Unless I misunderstood the meaning of "monitoring".

Comment: Well, we don't know if the user is affiliated or not. That's why I wrote "if". Even if they are, it's still acceptable to post Q&A about practical programming questions (related to code or real stack trace) that are unsuitable to be documented on their own site.

Comment: Some appear to be close-worthy for lack of technical details, but otherwise, yeah... they seem on-topic (albeit not of great effort).

Comment: I'm not sure how this would ever class as self-promotion?? They aren't suggesting using a specific library that happens to be written by them, most of the questions and answers pull from the official documentation which is fine in my opinion.

Comment: The votes on the questions so far seem to indicate the usefulness of the questions well enough

Comment: I don't want to Hijack this question, but it does lead to me wondering whether scrapping Q&A (bot or manually) of on-topic questions of third parties is permissible and without liability.

Comment: @BrettCaswell - it's permissible (see ToS), but only with proper attribution of the content referenced (SO link, author name retained, link to author's profile here, etc)

Answer (score 9):

I don't see this as "obvious" self-promotion.

I don't see "general problem" questions being answered with "Use product X from company Y to solve it".

To me it looks more like "I'm using product X from company Y, how do I solve problem Z" questions.

I think it's fine to ask question about specific commercial products.

I think it's fine if such questions are answered by company staff (don't know if that's the case here).

I agree that company self-answered question can be a "grey area". If a company posted lots of self-answered questions, it could be an attempt to promote a product by drawing attention to their product but I don't see that happening here. It's like 5 questions in 14 days. That's not enough to be a promotion attempt.

If a company posts (a few) self-answered questions on topics they know often causes problems for their users, I don't consider that a self-promotion problem.

So all together - I can't see a problem with this specific user.

Comment: i think he should post his affiliation i his profil, so that if he has 50 or more links to the same page, it must be clear where he stands.